# Change attachment download folder

Tags: email, exchange, file-management, attachments

I use the builtin mail app to access a Exchange mail account. I have set it to download all attachments automatically, and it puts them in the Downloads folder. There is only an option to choose between internal and external storage for attachments, but you can't choose the folder. Is there and config file or similar that I can tweak to change this?

Comment: Just curious, but why would you want your email client to automatically download all of your attachments? Seems like kind of a security hole, even for a linux based system...

Comment: I download all the new mail when I'm using Wifi so that attachments are not downloaded later on a 3G connection

Comment: Ok, it is less of a security threat on Android devices because you are less likely to get a virus that can run on Android through email, I have personally had viruses sneak in this way on desktop computers. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you are wondering if you can change the download folder by changing some sort of config file. This sort of behavior has been sort of deprecated in Android. As an Android Developer, we are supposed to make all of our cache files private so that they cannot be accessed by another person or, more importantly, another program. Letting other programs root around in your files was a big security hole for linux, so it is kind of frowned upon now, so I would be very surprised if you found a config file where you could change the Download folder. If you want to be able to set your download folder, then you could try to find an app on the market that has such functionality.

And yes I know the frustration you are talking about, I used to use my Droid 3 for doing my school email and finding and opening attachments was next to impossible.

Comment: It would be nice if you could specify where you wanted a certain download to go. For one of my accounts I sometimes would like to save attachments directly to a network drive and avoid the hassle and overhead of going through the local filesystem.